# Не отображаются кнопки "Изменить", "Удалить" в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Не отображаются кнопки при наведении мышью на элемент.

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
$i=0;
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    $file = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"], array('width'=>1600, 'height'=>900), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, true);

    if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) { 
        $res = CIBlockSection::GetByID($arItem["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]);

        if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())
            $section=$ar_res['NAME'];   
    } 

    if($i==0):?>
        <div class="main-news" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
            <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                <img src="<?=$file['src']?>">
                <div class="title">
                    <?echo $arItem["NAME"]?>
                </div>
            </a>            
            <div class="date">
                <?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?> | <span><?=$section?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="all-news">
    <?else:?>
        <div class="news-item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
            <? if ($file['src'] != ""): ?>
            <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                <img src="<?=$file['src']?>">
                <div class="title">
                    <?echo $arItem["NAME"]?>
                </div>
            <? else: ?>
            <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" class="picholder">
                <?echo $arItem["NAME"]?>
            <? endif; ?>
            </a>
            <div class="date">
                <?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?> | <span><?=$section?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endif;

    $i++;
endforeach;?>
</div>
```

В коде всё вроде правильно прописано но кнопки рядом с main-news и news-item не отображаются.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А режим правки включен?

Comment: Проверил твой код, у меня отработал и кнопки отобразились - код действительно верный
Проверь консоль может в ней ошибки, или стили, мог ошибиться в стилях и эти кнопки сейчас где-то или абсолютом или флоатом сбились в кучу.
Но вероятнее ошибка в консоли

Comment: Самое интересное, что в HTML коде не могу найти это меню, хотя есть js код описывающий данный элемент. Вероятно этот js не выполняется..

Comment: @NikolajSarry, конечно.

Comment: if(window.BX)BX.ready() в которой создается BX.CMenuOpener и вызывается BX.admin.setComponentBorder.

Вызов в консоли этого фрагмента привёл к нужному результату.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в самом начале цикла подключается поддержка Эрмитажа. Попробуй почистить кэш компонента/страницы

```
$this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Тут на самом деле всё намного веселее и глубже: в теге script, который и должен выводит эти компоненты, стоит ограничение на 10000 знаков, из-за чего весь скрипт не выполняется. Есть мысли где это ограничение можно снять?